# How to manage a user-page refresh with Vuejs/Vue-Router

Tags: vuejs2, single-page-application

I'm building an SPA (my first!) with VueJS/Laravel to present crop pest information to growers. From the home page, a new view is populated with an ex-database list of pests; clicking on any given pest triggers a new view containing a factsheet about that pest.

Everything works as I hoped, but if I refresh the browser window when either of the latter two views are active, all I get is the javascript object listing that "fuels" the view.

How do I guard against this type of user action?

I'm unsure what part of my code to present; if it helps, my router code is here:

```
export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Vue.component( 'Home', require( './components/Home.vue' ) )
        },
        { path: "/pest", component: Vue.component( 'Pest', require( './components/Pest.vue' ) ), children:
            [
                {
                    path: '',
                    name: 'pestnoteslist',
                    component: Vue.component( 'PestNotesList', require( './components/PestNotesList.vue' ) )
                },
                {
                    path: '/pest/:id',
                    name: 'pestnotes',
                    component: Vue.component( 'PestNotes', require( './components/PestNotes.vue' ) ),
                    props: true
                }
            ]
        },

        { path: '*', redirect: "/"}     // { path: '*', redirect: {name: 'home'}}
    ]
});
```

Comment: I had this issue in the past, it's a webpack thing. You need to request webpack to redirect all routes to the index.html.

I don't remember the configuration,  but are you working with Vue-Cli3? Because I think it is set as a Base default there...
Are you?

Comment: are you updating the browser urls?  `this.$router.replace(newURL);`

Comment: @Yaniv - Thanks. I'm using Laravel as well so I guess my default route will be to index.php. I subsequently found that changing my VueRouter mode from history to hash 'solved' the problem - which suggests a server tweak for the default file is required. Edwin - thanks, but not sure if your comment is something to do or to avoid.